# Getting the maximum value of vertical scroll using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my view code I used jQuery it works and I didn't have any problem until I have changed the screen resolution it stops working. I know where is the problem but I can't solve it look at the code :

```
@model PNUBOOKIR.Models.ProductModels
@{
    Layout = null;           
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Index</title>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var endRun = false;
    var PageNO = 1;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ((($("#container").outerHeight() - 796) == ($(this).scrollTop())) && (!endRun)) {
            endRun = true;
            Load();
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Load();
        return false;
    });

    function Load() {
        var BtnShowMore = document.getElementById("BtnShowMore");
        BtnShowMore.innerHTML = "Loading...";
        $.ajax({ type: "Post",
            url: "Product" + "/" + "GetHomeEventAjax",
            data: "{" + "PageNO" + ":" + PageNO + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function succ(data, states) {
                if (states == "success") {
                    if (data.Content != null) {
                        var EventListArea = document.getElementById("result");
                        $('#result > tbody:last').append(data.Content);
                        PageNO = PageNO + 50;
                        BtnShowMore.innerHTML = "More";
                        endRun = false;
                    }
                    else BtnShowMore.innerHTML = "Loading is complete";
                }
            },
            error: function err(result) { alert(result.responseText); }
        });
    }        
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" border="1" style="width: 450px; direction: rtl;"
            id="result">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>کد کالا</th>
                    <th>نام کتاب</th>
                    <th>ناشر</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a style="width: 200px" id="BtnShowMore">
            Load</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the scroll event script I need to found out what is the maximum value of vertical scroll so I get the container outer-Height but is wasn't exactly the maximum value it is 796px greater than it in the 1280x1024 screen resolution it can be different in different screen resolution setting. I need some help what should be instead of "796" number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#container").attr({ scrollTop: $("#container").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

Starting from JQuery 1.9.1, you'll need:

```
$("#container").scrollTop($("#container").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

Comment: it returns [object Object] what should I do with it ?

Comment: Nothing. You just call that line.

Comment: but how about the number 796 I must remove it? Could you add more description to your answer please

Comment: Sorry, it more intended to point you in the direction than do it for you. Basically whenever you want to scroll to the bottom of #container, you call that line of code. It completely replaces the whole $(window).scroll() portion of code you have there (however you'd have to deal with the function call I see in there).

Comment: $(window).scroll raised but $("#container").scroll never raised

Comment: This doesn't work with jQuery 1.9.1. The .attr('scrollHeight') returns undefined but .prop('scrollHeight') does the trick. .prop() was added in 1.6. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 43):

The posted answer is incorrect; the maximum value of `scrollTop` is not `scrollHeight`, it's `scrollHeight - outerHeight`.

---

This will give you the correct value:

```
var elem = $("#container");
var maxScrollTop = elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.outerHeight();
```

Comment: you save my day :D

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this with-out jQuery.

```
document.getElementById('container').scrollTop = document.getElementById('container').scrollHeight;
```

using jQuery it did't worked for me, so try this one if having problem with above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contentHeight = 0;
var scrollBottom = $('#container').scrollTop() + $('#container').height();

$('#container').children().each(function() {
     contentHeight += $(this).height();
});

if (scrollBottom >= contentHeight) {
     // You have reached the bottom, do some stuff.
}
```