# Jquery max value

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a small test whereby a div slides depending on the scroll depth.

I was just wondering how to set

A) a starting point (scrolltop = x something)

B) how to set the max value?

```
var pxlCount = 0
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    pxlCount = $(document).scrollTop()/50;
    $('.pop').css('margin-right', -400 + parseInt(pxlCount * 20) + 'px');
});
```

**[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/joris_d/pen/NXEgEJ)**

As it is I don't want the div to move further than the edge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the maximum value of vertical scroll using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027278/getting-the-maximum-value-of-vertical-scroll-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To define a starting point and a max value, check the `scrollTop()` of `window` inside your scroll handler :

```
var startingPoint = 200;
var maxValue = 600;
var pxlCount = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= startingPoint && $(window).scrollTop() <= maxValue){
        pxlCount = $(document).scrollTop()/50;
        $('.pop').css('margin-right', -400 + parseInt(pxlCount * 20) + 'px');
    }
});
```

Comment: @VTodorov The part where 400 appears has nothing to do with OP's request. He only wanted a way to limit the effects of his scroll handler to a defined range.